# Can I assign JIRA permission schemes to projects in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, permissions, project, jira

I haven't been able to find any info about this, whether or not it's possible.

I'm writing an external app that I want to give the ability to really put projects on hold (i.e. browse only, can't create/modify/etc... issues), and remove that hold. Everything is working fine in terms of the communication between the two apps, but I can't find the API hook to change the permission scheme associated with a project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me if this is just something that can't be done?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

First you should use [validateUpdateProjectSchemes](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/project/ProjectService.html#validateUpdateProjectSchemes%28com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User,%20java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.Long%29) from ProjectService class (to get the projectService object you simply inject it into your constructor).

```
UpdateProjectSchemesValidationResult validationResult = projectService.validateUpdateProjectSchemes(
    user,
    permissionSchemeID,
    null,
    null);
```

Then, check if validation result is valid and actually update the project with chosen permission scheme using [updateProjectSchemes](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/project/ProjectService.html#updateProjectSchemes%28com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.ProjectService.UpdateProjectSchemesValidationResult,%20com.atlassian.jira.project.Project%29) method:

```
if (validationResult.isValid()){
    projectService.updateProjectSchemes(validationResult, project);
}
```